# How do I load a json file into Sencha Touch?

Tags: javascript, mobile, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to load a json-file into a list. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I'm getting no error.

Data.js:

```
Ext.regModel('Contact', {
    fields: ['bandName', 'playDate']
});

ListDemo.ListStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'Contact',
    sorters: 'bandName',
    getGroupString : function(record) {
        return record.get('bandName')[0];
    },

    /*data: [
        { bandName: "Bandname",      playDate: "Thursday 20:00" }
    ]*/

    proxy: {
        type: 'scripttag',
        url: 'http://domain.com/artists.json',
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
        },
        autoLoad: true
    }
});
```

Index.js:

ListDemo = new Ext.Application({
    name: "ListDemo",

```
launch: function() {

    ListDemo.detailPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        id: 'detailpanel',
        tpl: 'Hello, {bandName}!',
        dockedItems: [
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                items: [{
                    text: 'back',
                    ui: 'back',
                    handler: function() {
                        ListDemo.Viewport.setActiveItem('disclosurelist', {type:'slide', direction:'right'});
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    });

    ListDemo.listPanel = new Ext.List({
        id: 'disclosurelist',
        store: ListDemo.ListStore,
        itemTpl: '<div class="contact">{bandName}<br /><span style="font-size:12px;">{playDate}</span></div>',
        grouped: true,
        onItemDisclosure: function(record, btn, index) {
            ListDemo.detailPanel.update(record.data);
            ListDemo.Viewport.setActiveItem('detailpanel');
        }
    });

    ListDemo.Viewport = new Ext.Panel ({
        fullscreen: true,
        layout: 'card',
        cardSwitchAnimation: 'slide',
        items: [ListDemo.listPanel, ListDemo.detailPanel]
    });

}
});
```

My json-file:

```
[
    { "id": 1, "bandName": "Moe", "playDate": "Thursday" },
    { "id": 2, "bandName": "Larry", "playDate": "Thursday" },
    { "id": 3, "bandName": "Curly", "playDate": "Thursday" }    
]
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON-file is in array format. Add a node that has this array as value, and then set the data node (of your proxy) in your Sencha Touch file to this node.
The JSON would look as follows:

```
"data": [
    { "id": 1, "bandName": "Moe", "playDate": "Thursday" },
    { "id": 2, "bandName": "Larry", "playDate": "Thursday" },
    { "id": 3, "bandName": "Curly", "playDate": "Thursday" }    
]
```

Comment: Hi, I'm new with json.. How would I create that?

Answer (score 0):

You should using Chrome browse and Chrome Developer tools to debug your code. Your json file is correct.

Comment: It is correct JSON, but is it correct so Sencha Touch can understand it? They require certain structures to parse it correctly..

Comment: you can refer json file in Sencha Touch examples